# Unable to install tensorflow graphics

Tags: tensorflow, graphics, levenberg-marquardt

I am trying to use Levenberg optimizer using the tfg.math.optimizer.levenberg_marquardt.minimize. I am following the installation instructions from https://www.tensorflow.org/graphics/install
On using: pip install --upgrade tensorflow-graphics, I get the following error:

ERROR: Failed building wheel for OpenEXR
Running setup.py clean for OpenEXR
Failed to build OpenEXR
Installing collected packages: OpenEXR, tensorflow-graphics
Running setup.py install for OpenEXR ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Could you please help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Linux and I needed to install libopenexr-dev with apt:

`sudo apt install libopenexr-dev`

After this `pip install tensorflow-graphics` run without problems.