# How can we use "tensorflow_graphic" with Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, optimization

I wanna use the optimiser "levenberg_marquardt" which is implemented in "tensorflow_graphics" with Keras.
I've attached a self-contained very basic example.

The problem is that I get the following error message:

**ValueError: Could not interpret optimizer identifier: <module 'tensorflow_graphics.math.optimizer.levenberg_marquardt' from '/home/marcf/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_graphics/math/optimizer/levenberg_marquardt.py'>*

Do you know how I can overcome this problem?

Cheers.

CODE

---

- 

```
*from keras.models import Sequential


import keras
import keras.backend as kb
import tensorflow as tf

import tensorflow_graphics as tfg
import tensorflow_graphics.math as tfg_math
import tensorflow_graphics.math.optimizer as tfg_math_optimizer
# The two last lines are needed if we want Python to recohgnise TFG optimizer. 

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66552679/unable-to-install-tensorflow-graphics
# sudo apt install libopenexr-dev
# pip install --upgrade tensorflow-graphics

model = keras.Sequential(  [keras.layers.Dense(3, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=[4]) ]); # No hidden layer. 5 input variables and 6 output variables. Linear model. 
    
    # https://keras.io/api/optimizers/
      
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate = 0.09); # Learning rate.
    #model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer=optimizer); # Minimising the RMSE*
    
    
opti = tfg.math.optimizer.levenberg_marquardt
    # tfg.math.optimizer.levenberg_marquardt() doesn't work with brackets!
    
    
model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', optimizer = opti, metrics = ['mean_squared_error']); # stochastic gradient descent
*

I could not find any relevant forum discussion on this.
```

Comment: Are you sure if it is compatible with Keras?

Comment: `levenberg_marquardt` and Keras optimizers implemented differently, in the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/graphics/blob/master/tensorflow_graphics/math/optimizer/levenberg_marquardt.py) you can see there are no `tf.Variable`s which is completely different from other Keras optimizers. Long story short, you need to write this as a custom optimizer in Keras.

Comment: `levenberg_marquardt` is not a valid optimizer alone to call without minimize(). You need to use this optimizer algorithm with its minimize function. Please check the link how to define and use [tfg.math.optimizer.levenberg_marquardt.minimize()](https://www.tensorflow.org/graphics/api_docs/python/tfg/math/optimizer/levenberg_marquardt/minimize).